# PHP Facebook SDK login unreliable

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a strange behavior on my script. Using Facebook PHP SDK I create a button with a link to getLoginUrL() :

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'email',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.myurl.com')
);
```

Most of the time this works very well and I can access the user information using the following bit of code

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['front']['user_id']) || !is_numeric($_SESSION['front']['user_id']))
    {
      if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
        try {
            $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
            $basic = $facebook->api('/me?access_token=' . $access_token);
            if (is_array($basic) && is_numeric($user_id)) {
                $user = get_user_id_facebook($basic);
                $_SESSION['front']['user_id'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['front']['user_name'] = $basic['name'];
                $_SESSION['front']['email'] = $basic['email'];
                $_SESSION['front']['fbid'] = $basic['id'];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
      }
   }
```

The problem is that sometimes I really cannot access the user information... why is this so unsteady? My php version is 5.3.2

Comment: If you can upgrade your PHP to 5.4+, you can use the newer SDK:  github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Comment: really cannot upgrade. is that the problem ?

Comment: It's not the problem but would be a solution.  You should be checking if $user_id is not 0, and logging any exceptions which occur.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unreliable as you're only executing the code if `code` exists in the GET or POST request. What you really should be doing is checking if the user is logged in, e.g.

```
if ( $facebook->getUser() != 0 ) {
    // get profile information
} else {
    // log user in
}
```

The `code` parameter won't always existing on your page, as it's returned by Facebook on successful login. But not when the user accesses your page directly or via bookmark.

Comment: sorry, i'm executing this code IF user is not logged in and IF code exists (returning from facebook login)